# Can't start GParted on a Live CD

Tags: partitioning, live-cd

I can't run GParted on the Live CD because something called root must run it and I don't have the necessary privileges.

Comment: sorry i'm only 14 give me a minute and i will post the error message

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Ubuntu or any gtk / ubuntu based distro, press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then enter this command:

```
gksudo gparted
```

If you are using Kubuntu (KDE) live CD, press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and enter this command:

```
kdesu gparted
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in partitioner. Click install ubuntu and choose something else from the list this will enter the partitioner interface.

Good luck.